# Rework JavaScript Function to make reusable by all Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have working JavaScript but I was trying to rework the multiple functions to be one
common function so I can reuse as I build dynamic HTML.

My attempt has failed - any insight would be appreciated.

This is my attempt to make a common function but this doesn't work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#'+ this.id +'Div').hide();
    $('button#'+ this.id).click(function() {
        $('#'+ this.id +'Div').toggle(400);
    });
});

});//]]>
</script>
```

This is the functions that are working that I am trying to replace with above

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideDetails1Div').hide();
    $('button#hideDetails1').click(function() {
        $('#hideDetails1Div').toggle(400);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideDetails2Div').hide();
    $('button#hideDetails2').click(function() {
        $('#hideDetails2Div').toggle(400);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideDetails3Div').hide();
    $('button#hideDetails3').click(function() {
        $('#hideDetails3Div').toggle(400);
    });
});


});//]]>
</script>
```

Button hooked to function that hides an associated DIV

```
<button id="hideDetails1"  title="" class="primaryButton2">show box 1</button>
....
<br /> <!-- hide div -->
<div id="hideDetails1Div" style="border:1px solid red; width:300px; height:100px;">
     <h2>box 1</h2>
</div><!-- END OF HIDE DIV -->
```

Comment: I would suggest using common classes instead of ids if you would like to do this.

Comment: Your interpolating the ID and therefore only getting a reference to **one** div not all.

Comment: `$(document).ready` inside `window.load`?? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Danny mentioned in the comments, use a common class, instead of different IDs. Additionally, make use of the `data-*` attribute in order to store the target div. Also, you don't need the `$(window).load` wrapper when you're using `$(document).ready`.

So. you'd have something like this:

```
<button class="toggle" data-target="div1"></button>

$('.toggle').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#' + this.data('target')).toggle(400);
});
```

One of the reasons your initial attempt is failing is because you're trying to do the hiding things using `this` inside of the `$(document).ready` function. In that case, `this` is referring to the document.

There are a few different ways you can go about hiding the divs on load if you need that. Again, the easiest way (in my opinion) is with a class. Just attach a class to the divs, let's say "hideLoad". Then, add a little JS to hide them all in your ready function:

```
$('.hideLoad').hide();
```

Alternatively, you can target the divs by ID and loop through them to hide them, but that requires you knowing the IDs, and having to add to that list every time you add a div.

Answer (score 2):

Use classes. But if you must use ID's:

```
$('#hideDetails1Div,#hideDetails2Div,#hideDetails3Div').hide();
$('button[id^="hideDetails"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#'+this.id+'Div').toggle(400);
});
```

Comment: @Archer - decided to go with a more specific approach... since the naming convention isn't really targetable using attribute selectors. I could do `[id$=Div]` (ends with 'Div'), but I feel it's too broad and might interfere with other things on the page.

Comment: @megawac -- they're not wanting to hide the buttons, but the associated divs.

Comment: I agree totally.  I removed the comment once I'd looked at the code a bit harder anyway.  They're not the friendliest of IDs and I'd read some of them as the same thing when they weren't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hideDiv('#div1', '#show_div1');
    hideDiv('#div2', '#show_div2');
    hideDiv('#div3', '#show_div3');
});
function hideDiv(divId, toggleId) {
    $(divId).hide();
    $(toggleId).click(function() {
        $(divId).toggle(400);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Working demo: [jsfiddle.net/H9ZG5/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/H9ZG5/2/)